# how to search for latest content on google?

Tags: search

in google search box when we type something like " 'java code' + inurl:javalobby " we will get the search results where the website link contains the string javalobby and the page will contain the string java code.

Similarly is there a way to search the latest updated content in the internet which will contain the keyword entered in the search box ?

Thanks.

Comment: click the 'more search tools' on the left side of the results.

Comment: is there way i can do this when entering the input in the search box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two tricks in google to narrow your search based on date. It is using either the keyword **daterange:startdate-enddate** or by **content creation date**.

**1.** Using the syntax **daterange:startdate-enddate** : The catch is that the date must be expressed as a [Julian date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day), a continuous count of days since noon UTC on January 1, 4713 BC. So, for example, July 8, 2002 is Julian date 2452463.5 and May 22, 1968 is 2439998.5. Furthermore, Google isn't fond of decimals in its daterange: queries; use only integers: 2452463 or 2452464. You can convert Julian dates [online here](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/JulianDate.php).

Example:- Geri Halliwell left the Spice Girls around May 27, 1998. If you wanted to get a lot of information about the breakup, you could try doing a date search in a ten-day window—Say, May 25 to June 4. That query would look like this:

```
"Geri  Halliwell"  "Spice  Girls"  daterange:2450958-2450968
```

**2.** Searching by **content creation date** : Try adding a string of common date formats to your query. If you wanted something from May 2003, for example, you could try appending:

`("May  *  2003"  |  "May  2003"  |  05/03  |  05/*/03)`

A query like that uses up most of your ten-query limit, however, so it's best to be judicious— perhaps by cycling through these formats one a time. If any one of these is giving you too many results, try restricting your search to the title tag of the page.

If you're feeling really lucky you can search for a full date, like May 9, 2003. Your decision then is if you want to search for the date in the format above or as one of many variations: 9 May 2003, 9/5/2003, 9 May 03, and so forth. Exact-date searching will severely limit your results and shouldn't be used except as a last-ditch option.

When using date-range searching, you'll have to be flexible in your thinking, more general in your search than you otherwise would be (because the date-range search will narrow your results down a lot), and persistent in your queries because different dates and date ranges will yield very different results. But you'll be rewarded with smaller result sets that are focused on very specific events and topics.